# generating random graph undirected

Tags: c++, graph

I need help whenever i try to make the adj_matrix[u][v]  == adj_matrix[v][u]  for the same weight it doesn't apply and can anyone tell me if i am on the correct path ?

and is there a way to set the matrix without edge to an X  instead of a 0?

```
  int gen_random_graph(int n)
 {
    srand(time(0));
    int adj_matrix[n][n];
    for(int u = 0; u < n; u++)
    {
        for (int v = u; v < n; v++)   //generating a N x N matrix  based on the # of vertex input
        {
            bool edgeOrNot = rand() % 2;   //decide whether it has an edge or not
            adj_matrix[u][v] = adj_matrix[v][u] = edgeOrNot;
            cout << u << " " << v << " " << adj_matrix[u][v] << endl;
            if(adj_matrix[u][v] == true)
            {
                adj_matrix[v][u] = true;
                if(u == v)                            //We can't have i = j in an undirected graph
                {
                    adj_matrix[u][v] = -1;
                }
                cout << u << " " << v << " " << adj_matrix[u][v] << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                adj_matrix[v][u] = -1;
                cout << u << " " << v << " " << adj_matrix[u][v] << "else" <<  endl;
            }
        }

    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for(int j = i; j < n; j++)           //create the N x N with edges and sets the weight between the edge randomly
        {
            if(adj_matrix[i][j] == true)
            {
                    int weight1 = rand()%10 + 1;
                    adj_matrix[i][j] = adj_matrix[j][i] = weight1;
                    cout << " ( " << i << "," << j << " ) " << "weight: " << adj_matrix[i][j] << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int N;
    cout << "Enter number of vertices" << endl;
    cin >> N;
    gen_random_graph(N);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead 'X' I recommend use -1 value. There's a sample:

```cpp
void gen_random_graph(int n) {
    srand(time(0));
    int adj_matrix[n][n];

    for(int u = 0; u < n; u++) {
        for (int v = u; v < n; v++) { //you don't need to calculate weight twice so loop starts from u
            if(v == u) {
                adj_matrix[u][v] = -1;
            }
            else {
                int weight = rand() % 10 - 1;
                adj_matrix[u][v] = adj_matrix[v][u] = weight;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can check value of edge. For -1 it doesn't exist.

Comment: yo ur a genius it fixed my THING the v = u !!!!!!!!!  can you help me with one my problem? How can i return (M,L ) such that M = matrix  L = list.... would just be return (adj_matrix, and we just use list to list all adj list?

Comment: @Darkflame I'm not sure what do you mean by "list to list all adj list" but simple use struct with your matrix and array of lists.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your algorithm among other things. It's one thing to use `int adj_matrix` to store `bool`s, but storing `'X'`, a `char` is something I would avoid.

For storing the same weights I would try:

```
const int weight = rand() % 10 + 1;
adj_matrix[u][v] = weight;
adj_matrix[v][u] = weight;
```

The compiler may try to invoke `rand()` twice, once for each statement. In the above you invoke `rand()` only once.

In general I would use STL containers such as `std::vector<int>`, and `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`, although the latter is not ideal from memory footprint point of view.

Instead of `'X'` I would use `std::numeric_limits<int>::min` or `max`, which may not be equal to `rand() % 10 + 1`.

Comment: the X are for the part where its not connected with edge like (1,1) and (0,0) shouldnt have a edge in an undirect graph and i tried that const int weight didnt seem to work do i have to put the const in weight outside the for loops ? but then it wouldnt generate new one

Comment: Again, I would use the same type, in this case `int`, with a special value as shown above. I would not mix `char` with `int`.